# Full recordset copy from sql to excel using vbscript

Tags: vb.net

Experts please clarify my doubt.

I have my VB script to copy 65 columns of my resultset of a stored procedure call (which returns 68 columns) into an Excel sheet.

My stored procedure query returns the complete recordset, but I couldn't get the complete resultset using vbscript. I tried to specify every column I want, then tried counting the columns alone but only 50 columns are getting into Excel, not the full recordset.

And why only first 50 columns, not the whole set?

Thanks in advance.

I tried to display only headers in Excel (only 50 fields displayed)

```
For i = 1 To rstcostbase.fields.Count 
    worksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = rstcostbase.fields(i).Name 

Next i
```

Looping through individual row and column even then got only 50 columns data.

Comment: So you put a breakpoint on the 'For' line and hovered your mouse over Count in rstcostbase.fields.Count, and . . .

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**: Either 1) you're working with ActiveX Data Objects (ADODB) or 2) RecordSets in vb all work similarly...

Some time ago I found this approach on the web to extract recordsets into a string in standard .csv formatting. Have a go and see if it helps you out.

```
Function RecordsetToCSV(rsData As ADODB.Recordset, 
                        Optional ShowColumnNames As Boolean = True, 
                        Optional NULLStr As String = "") As String

    Dim K As Long, RetStr As String = ""

    If ShowColumnNames Then
        For K = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
            RetStr = RetStr & ",""" & rsData.Fields(K).Name & """"
        Next K

        RetStr = Mid(RetStr, 2) & vbNewLine
    End If

    RetStr = RetStr & """" & rsData.GetString(ADODB.StringFormatEnum.adClipString, -1, """,""", """" & vbNewLine & """", NULLStr)
    RetStr = Left(RetStr, Len(RetStr) - 3)

    Return RetStr
End Function
```

It's older code but it checks out...

Comment: Thanks ben, but this is not working for me. could you pls me guide me why I couldn't get all records into the excel